# Hooks support in react dev tools?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-devtools

I read in the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html) that:

> React Hooks are now **supported by React DevTools**. They are also
>   supported in the latest Flow and TypeScript definitions for React. We
>   strongly recommend enabling a new lint rule called
>   eslint-plugin-react-hooks to enforce best practices with Hooks. It
>   will soon be included into Create React App by default.

Then I updated React to 16.8 and started using hooks. But after doing `useState()` and `useContext()` in my first component, I couldn't properly inspect them using React Dev Tools (see picture below).

Is there a way around this?

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error,setError] = useState(null);
  const [productDetails,setProductDetails] = useState(null);

  const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext);
```

[image]

Comment: Did you upgrade React's devtools extension?

Comment: I've got the 3.6.0 which seems to be the latest. Is yours working as intended?

Comment: Looking at your screenshot again it looks like the hooks state is showing up correctly, what seems to be missing? It's pretty basic at the moment, but this issue is tracking further features that would make it nicer to use: https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/1215.

Comment: But state variable names and context values are not showing. How can I be sure which one I'm looking at if I have 5 boolean state variables? Thanks. It seems that a new version of the React DevTools is coming. No release date yet, though. On Twitter, Dan Abramov advised to use [this one](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1106006760421240833) until then

Comment: Regarding order - I think they will be ordered in the order that `useState` was called in your component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE December 2019**

React Dev Tools v4 with Hooks Support **has been released.**

[React Dev Tools - Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi)

[React Dev Tools - Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/react-devtools/)

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The new version of the React DevTools might have already been release and that's what you should be using.

But until then, what you can use is:

https://react-devtools-experimental-chrome.now.sh/

Got this answer from one of Dan Abramov's [tweets](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1105864302098112513)

Comment: if anyone else finds this and has trouble getting it to work (windows users) you need to use a zip program like 7-zip to extract the files from the .crx file into a folder then in the chrome extensions screen in developer mode click "load unpacked" and select that folder.